# thunderbird can't connect to my email box

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot

I have installed mail server successfully on my vps according to
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-postfix-e-mail-server-with-dovecot.
I create user joe with passwd "ps1" with root successfully.
When i lgoin into my vps , joe@mydomain.com can sent and receive email via postfix and dovecot .
There two passwords here for joe : one is for joe to login into vps ,one is for joe to enter the email .
which one will i fill in the password in thunderbird?I tried tow of them ,all failures.

Why can't connect my mail on my vps via thunderbird locally?

Comment: Firefox? Or Thunderbird?

Comment: sorry it is thunderbird

Comment: why you have two password for joe. joe is a system user, and you should use the password you entered after `adduser joe`. ps: you know that mydomain.com is an example domain just for documentation example in DO doc ?

Comment: i have changed mydomain.com into my own domain ,and the domain is ready to bind with my vps ip,and i can send and receive email via joe@mydomain.com

Comment: The passwd when entered after adduser joe is tested,thunderbird can't connect it.